# Change wp-content/uploads to uploads/%postname%/%image%

Tags: images, media, directory, uploads

When uploading an image to a post, I want to change it so that it grabs the postname or post_id and places it in a folder like uploads/%postname%/

Is there a simple method of doing so?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use `define('UPLOADS', 'wp-content/folder');` in my config.php file right under `require_once(ABSPATH.’wp-settings.php’);`

You can try to change the folder to something like %postname%
`define('UPLOADS', 'wp-content/%postname%');`

Comment: Aye, I used this to change it to a folder outside wp-content which works fine.. sadly I don't think %postname% will work as it breaks something I'm using for an 'avatar' uploader.. 

I'm using a plugin called "comment images" and I think I may have to edit that instead as the image comes up blank if I use the %postname% method in config.php

Comment: Hm that's a pickle. Believe me you don't want to change plugin code. For exactly the same reason why you don't want to change WP core code: if you upgrade, all your modifications are changed. Maybe you can hook into it from your functions.php and write an if/else statement that defines wether the upload is from the plugin or the WP-uploader?

Comment: Looks like the plugin uses wp_upload_bits anyway.. it grabs the post_id so it shouldn't be a problem getting the postname as a variable but I can't figure out how to use it within this wp_upload_bits function.... wagrghhhg

Comment: Try to change `$comment_image_file = wp_upload_bits( $comment_id . '.' . $file_ext, null, file_get_contents( $_FILES[ $comment_image_id ]['tmp_name'] ) );` to  `$comment_image_file = wp_upload_bits( $comment_id, ${post_name} . '.' . $file_ext, null, file_get_contents( $_FILES[ $comment_image_id ]['tmp_name'], $_FILES[ $comment_post_name ]['tmp_name'] ) );` Or maybe you can change the upload location of the plugin so the two wont have problems with each other?

Comment: Thanks, well I tried doing a few modifications for the 4th parameter but it doesn't seem to recognise any folder creation. I can make it so the filename has the postname + username which I guess will do for now...